# Check for active users in rails if the users stays in one page and dont click through the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build an rails app and trying to see what users are online. I know how to implement the method to show online users if the user clicks through my app, but lets assume that my app is only 1 page, so there are no links to be clicked. How would I track the users online without the user having to click anywhere? Also i if the user has been idle for 15 min i will need to update the status to idle instead of online and if the user closes the browser or navigates to another page the status goes to offline.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably they interact in some way with the page (ajax perhaps?) so you'll need to detect those interactions and use them to determine if the user is idle or not. You could use javascript's [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) to determine when they have left the page.

Comment: Thank you mike onbeforeunload is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: No probs, good luck with the site. If this adequately answers your original question, I think the protocol is to mark the answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to make *AJAX pings* to your server side like:

```
$.get( '/user_activity/ping' );
```

You can do it automatically using [JS Timers](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) or explicitly when the user interacts with the page some how.

Comment: Yes fgullien i am already using this i could not track the event when the user navigates away from the page or closes the browser. Now everything is complete.